# HttpClient Add "api-version=1.0" to accept header

Tags: http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient, .net-6.0

I am using .NET6 and have added versioning to my ASP web API.

Rather than include the version number in the url mysite.com/api/v1/controller I would like to add the api-version to either the Accept header or as a separate custom header.

What I have tried so far only produces errors, any help would be appreciated.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ServiceResponse<DataResponseDto>> Login(DataDto bodyParams)
{

    try {
    
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyParams), Encoding.UTF8, $"application/json");

        var httpClient = _httpClient.CreateClient("MyAPI");
        

        // The various Accept headers I have tried
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json; api-version=1.0"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json; api-version=1.0");
        

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("Data/Send", httpContent);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();                                         // Throws an exception if not 200 OK

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse<DataResponseDto>>(stream);

        return result;

    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        // logger and stuff

        return result;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the response I always get is "The format of value 'application/json; api-version=1.0' is invalid." It looks ok to me. I tried the request in postman and it works.

I then tried just adding my own custom header

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version", "1.0");
```

However, the response was "Response status code does not indicate success: 415 (Unsupported Media Type)."

Ay help in Sending the version of my API in the headers would be appreciated. Not much information for this online, most of the search results are sending the HTTP version or writing their own custom versioning controllers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the ".Parse()" from my first attempt.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json; api-version=2.0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is a problem:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json; api-version=1.0");
```

Instead, try:

```
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;");
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version", "1.0");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I still get the same error - "The format of value 'application/json;' is invalid."

Comment: I would use a tool like https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler to capture the HTTP traffic and explore what is actually sent, can you then post a sample request in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned **application/json** mediaType in **StringContent** constructor, so you don't need to mention it separately. For adding extra **api-version** header use **Add** method of **DefaultRequestHeaders** collection:

```
    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyParams),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            $"application/json");

    var httpClient = _httpClient.CreateClient("MyAPI");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version", "1.0");
```